# Mistake on Def Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

im typing this program where i have to use a for loop in it. The program should look like this:

```
######
#####
####
###
##
#
```

Here is the program i have written so far at the moment:

```
n = 6

print_triangle2(n):
    for i in range (0, n):
        for j in range (0, n - i):
    print ("#", end='')
```

Im getting close to my answer but i keep getting a syntax error on my def function. I dont what the deal and how to fix the problem. Please help.

Comment: "I keep getting an error."  But you won't tell us what the error is?

Comment: Indent matters *a lot* in Python. That is trivially *invalid syntax* as 1) there is no 'body' in the inner loop (see indent), and; 2) there is also no `def`. Fix syntax errors before even worrying about logic errors ..

Comment: You refer to your "`def` function" but literally never typed `def` in your code...

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of syntax errors in your code:

Any Python function has to start with `def` - otherwise the interpreter will not know how to interpret your definition, where it starts and what it means.

Additionally, your **print** function has to be properly indented into the loop, otherwise you'll have **IndentationError**.

Your code contains a redundant inner loop, which you can easily omit by optimizing your code. You just need the indexes properly set and use concatenation, rather then tuple.

Do it like this - then you don't need the inner loop:

```
def print_triangle2(n):
    for i in range (0, n):
        print("#"*(n-i)+" "*i)


print_triangle2(6)
```

Comment: i dont know why but im still having trouble with the def function. It saying there a error for the colon but i dont know what

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Use that published answer as your starting point and debug it as you're learning.